# Visual studio 2XXX,MSbuild,VC++2XXX,Platform toolset and Windows SDK compatibilty

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I have started working on Visual studio few weeks ago. I did install the two different version of Microsoft Visual studio 2010 and 2017.I have the project downloaded from repository. I tried to build the project on VS 2017 and it gave me like >10000 errors same project I tried with VS 2010 and it did build. From these small experiment, I get little idea about VS version and platform toolset. So basically VS 2XXX is just the ide it uses v1xx as toolset version.

**Now my question is:**

***If I have to use the same project on higher version/lower version ,what should I need to do?**

***If I'm using VS2017 , can I use the platform toolset(v1xx)form lower version? Does the platform toolset depends upon Windows SDK version or VC++ environment.**

***How MSBuild differs from platform toolset?**

***What is MSVC (For some projects, I found to set its path from VS installation directory)?**

***if I'm using VS2010 and VC++2006 will it work together? OR do I need to install VC++2010 or higher ?**

***if I'm using VS2010,VC++ and platform toolset v100 which are all compatible.**

> case 1: Windows sdk 10, Will it work?
>
> case 2: Windows sdk 7, Will it work?

**Basically does it depends upon sdk version, now when VS and toolset are already compatible ?**

Comment: One question, one thread is recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I have to use the same project on higher version/lower version ,what should I need to do?

Each new version of Visual Studio generally supports most previous types of projects, files, and other assets. You can work with them as you always have, and provided that you don't depend on newer features, Visual Studio generally tries to preserve backwards compatibility with previous versions like Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, and Visual Studio 2012.

Support for some project types also changes over time. A newer version of Visual Studio may no longer support certain projects at all, or requires updating a project such that it's no longer backwards compatible.

See [Project migration and upgrade project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects) for more info.

> *If I'm using VS2017 , can I use the platform toolset(v1xx)form lower version? Does the platform toolset depends upon Windows SDK version or VC++ environment.

AFAIK, it should be depends upon Windows SDK version. According to this page on MSDN, you need to have the corresponding version of Visual Studio (2008 or 2010), or the relevant Windows SDK for the "Platform Toolset" drop down to list those versions:

> ```
> To change the target platform toolset, you must have the associated
> version of Visual Studio or the Windows Platform SDK installed.
> ```

.

> *How MSBuild differs from platform toolset?

You can check the document [WDK and MSBuild overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wdk-and-msbuild-overview) for some more details.

> *if I'm using VS2010 and VC++2006 will it work together? OR do I need to install VC++2010 or higher ?

Not sure. But you can use VC++2008 and above. Because we could not open [Visual C++ 6.0 project with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444618/how-can-i-convert-a-project-from-visual-c-6-0-to-visual-studio-express-2010), for VC++2008, check [Visual Studio 2010 with the Visual C++ 2008 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621621/how-can-i-use-visual-studio-2010-with-the-visual-c-2008-compiler).

> *if I'm using VS2010,VC++ and platform toolset v100 which are all compatible.

There is a Wikipedia page that covers the Microsoft Windows SDK has a comprehensive table describing the versions: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK